# How to Approve spend of one Token with Web3.js?

Tags: javascript, ethereum, solidity, web3js, binance-smart-chain

I seek via my web page of test to create a button which allows to authorize the expenditure of a Contract (Token)..
If I go to the page and I click I would like the script to load web3 (it loads well) then if I press the button that Metamask authorizes the spending of the contract.

Metamask opens fine and does request the connection for my test site on the BSC in Web3js. However I can't find the exact code for the approve function.

Here is the code:

```
<head>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/web3/1.7.0/web3.min.js'></script>
</head>
 
<button onclick="approvebutton();">Approve button to authorize tokens to be spent</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
if (typeof window.ethereum !== 'undefined') {
    ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts' });
} else {
    alert('Please install metamask')
}

var Web3 = require('web3');
const web3 = new Web3('https://bsc-dataseed1.binance.org:443');

 async function approvebutton() {

 /// APPROVE FUNCTION WITH THE CONTRACT 
 
 }
        
        
  </script>
```

I tried this approach but it doesn't work (metamask confirmation won't show up):

```
if (typeof window.ethereum !== 'undefined') {
    ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts' });
} else {
    alert('Please install metamask')
}

var Web3 = require('web3');
const web3 = new Web3('https://bsc-dataseed1.binance.org:443');
const Contract = ('0xContractAddress');
const spenderAdr = ('0xSpenderAddress');
const amount = ('AmountTokensNumber')


async function approvebutton(Contract,spenderAdr){
  Contract.methods.approve(spenderAddr, amount).send({
   from: ownerAddr
})
}
```

Metamask won't show up to confirm the TX.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the `approve` method takes 2 parameters, the `spender` and the `amount` so it will be something like this:

```
Contract.methods.approve(spenderAddr, amount).send({
   from: ownerAddr
})
```

The `gas` parameter is optional.

Comment: Thanks for the reply the if i have your code, Metamask won't show up to show the transaction : 


var Web3 = require('web3');
const web3 = new Web3('https://bsc-dataseed1.binance.org:443');
const Contract = ('0xContractAddress');
const spenderAdr = ('0xSpenderAddress');
const amount = ('1000000000000')


      async function approvebutton(Contract,spenderAdr){
  Contract.methods.approve(spenderAddr, amount).send({
   from: ownerAddr
})
}

Answer (score 1):

From the example code, I think you're missing the ABI (or Json Interface) for the contract and the instantiation of the contract via web3.eth.Contract() with the ABI and the contract address.

```
var Contract = new web3.eth.Contract(jsonInterface[, address][, options])
```

From that Contract instance you can then call the methods in the ABI, and that should trigger the Metamask modal.

From the docs:

```
Contract.methods.myMethod(123).send({from: '0xde0B295669a9FD93d5F28D9Ec85E40f4cb697BAe'})
.then(function(receipt){
    // receipt can also be a new contract instance, when coming from a "contract.deploy({...}).send()"
});
```

Or in your case, something along the lines of:

```
await Contract.methods.approve(spenderAddr, amount).send({ from: ownerAddr })
```

I also think that you're missing an await inside the approvebutton() function, to await the "promisevent" that the method call on the contract returns.

([Source https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth-contract.html#](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth-contract.html#), https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth-contract.html#id26)